# how to align parent bottom in android linear layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have a linearlayout

and I want to create at the bottom of it a slice.

I know there are some options, but I'm a bit confused

1) `android:layout_gravity:"bottom"` --> this doesn't work for me for some reason.

2) `android:gravity_weight="0"` and give the sibling before it `android:gravity_weight:"1"`

3) `android:height="wrap_content"` and give the sibling before it `android:height:"match_parent"`

I know how to do this using relativeLayout, but I want to practice linearLayout

what would you suggest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/signup_illu_why" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=""
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/signup_skip_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a RelativeLayout? It might be better suited for your need, and RelativeLayout is more efficient and the recommended way in general.

Comment: I know how to do this using relativeLayout, but I want to practice linearLayout

Comment: Similar one - check the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31987803/3624307

Answer (score 20):

Actually, you can set the parent element's gravity to bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/signup_illu_why" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=""
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/signup_skip_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but then everything will be at bottom

Comment: this is the right answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20633003/4548520 we should use `RelativeLayout` as parent and set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for child that we want to be at bottom

Comment: @user25 the question did not specify which subview should be bottom aligned so I assume he wants every subview to be at the bottom

Answer (score 12):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
                              ... >

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SomeViewThatNeedsGoBottom
                             ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.8" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can not add `android:orientation` to RelativeLayout.

Comment: yeah, please check edited answer. that was because i change layout directly instead of manually

Comment: I know how to do this using relativeLayout, but I want to practice linearLayout

Comment: Check my edited answer to do it with Linear Layout. You can do it with both layouts but it will be better if you use Relative Layout because that is more simple to use. Please change name of your image and color accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

surround your linear layout with framelayout and give gravity as bottom..
its simple than you think... many layouts are used just for easier move towards design

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width = "fill_parent">

<LinearLayout`
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity = "bottom"
android:orientation = "vertical">

<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android:text = "btn"/>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

example:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_weight="7"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="5">
  <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="some text"
     android:layout_weight="2"
     android:gravity="bottom" />
  <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="some text"
     android:layout_weight="1" />
  <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="some text"android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Relative in LinearLayout
and set Relative to matchparent, so you can use the layoutalignparentbottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/signup_illu_why" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=""
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/signup_skip_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Adding explanation to your answer would be helpful!

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.